# Automapper - Map flat data to hierarchical data

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

Let's say I have a data-set like below of groups with a parent group, second level group and a third level group. Lets say groupId is unique as well. Given this set of data, how can I use Automapper's solution to map such data into a hierarchical form?

```
"Groups": [
  {
    "ParentGroupId": "1",
    "ParentGroupName": "Parent Group 1",
    "SecondLevelGroupId": "11",
    "SecondLevelGroupName": "Second Level Group 1",
    "ThirdLevelGroupId": null,
    "ThirdLevelGroupName": null
  },
  {
    "ParentGroupId": "1",
    "ParentGroupName": "Parent 1"
    "SecondLevelGroupId": "12",
    "SecondLevelGroupName": "Second Level Group 2",
    "ThirdLevelGroupId": null,
    "ThirdLevelGroupName": null
  },
  {
    "ParentGroupId": "2",
    "ParentGroupName": "Parent 2"
    "SecondLevelGroupId": "21",
    "SecondLevelGroupName": "Second Level Group 1",
    "ThirdLevelGroupId": "31",
    "ThirdLevelGroupName": "Third Level Group 1"
  },
  {
    "ParentGroupId": "2",
    "ParentGroupName": "Parent 2"
    "SecondLevelGroupId": "21",
    "SecondLevelGroupName": "Second Level Group 1",
    "ThirdLevelGroupId": "32",
    "ThirdLevelGroupName": "Third Level Group 2"
  },
  {
    "ParentGroupId": "2",
    "ParentGroupName": "Parent 2"
    "SecondLevelGroupId": "22",
    "SecondLevelGroupName": "Second Level Group 2",
    "ThirdLevelGroupId": "33",
    "ThirdLevelGroupName": "Third Level Group 1"
  }
]
```

This is the hierarchical form I would like to have it mapped to (NOTE: JSON was hand-written, there might be some syntax errors)

```
"Groups": [
  {
    "GroupId": "1",
    "GroupName": "Parent Group 1",
    "ChildGroups": [
      {
        "GroupId": "11",
        "GroupName": "Second Level Group 1",
        "ChildGroups": null     
      },
      {
        "GroupId": "12",
        "GroupName": "Second Level Group 2",
        "ChildGroups": null      
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "GroupId": "2",
    "GroupName": "Parent 2"
    "ChildGroups": [
      {
        "GroupId": "21",
        "GroupName": "Second Level Group 1",
        "ChildGroups": [
          {
            "GroupId": "31",
            "GroupName": "Third Level Group 1",
            "ChildGroups": null
          },
          {
            "GroupId": "32",
            "GroupName": "Third Level Group 2",
            "ChildGroups": null
          }
        ] 
      },
      {
        "GroupId": "22",
        "GroupName": "Second Level Group 2",
        "ChildGroups": [
          {
            "GroupId": "33",
            "GroupName": "Third Level Group 1",
            "ChildGroups": null
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Automapper does map json data?

Comment: Well I'm just using json to represent how my data is structured.

Comment: @Mike, I know it's been some time, but did you ever solve this?